# Is this our fault? corringendum vs erratum

Tags: publications

We have been advised that a recent article of ours was incorrectly published as article type y instead of article type x. Article type x and y are very similar, having the same word counts, similar structure, and the same fees. It is just that the name of the article type (x vs y) is different.

It was our error for selecting the incorrect article type when submitting the article, but the article's title and some of the responses to the reviewer made it clear which article type we were aiming for.

The journal would now like us to issue a corringendum that states 'This article was supposed to be published as an x type article rather than a y type article'. However, I am wondering if this is more suitable as an erratum? i.e. that the journal was to blame for this error.

Comment: In my opinion, the editor should be responsible for specifying the correct article type in the acceptance letter; if that was not done, then the editor is at fault.  But this would be in the category of things which are not worth disputing.

Comment: I wonder if they are doing this because they got in trouble with an indexing service for labeling reviews as original research.

Comment: My experience is that some journals call their published documents fixing or pointing out mistakes "corrigendum" and others call them "erratum". Did you check that you can submit one or the other? Or is it always called "corrigendum" by this journal? I actually thought they were synonyms.

Comment: I had wondered if it's related to their stats. Perhaps they want to demonstrate diversity in types of articles. 

There is an option to submit either a corrigendum or erratum for this journal. As a general rule, publishers issue an erratum for a production error (i.e., an error introduced during the publishing process) and a corrigendum for an author's error..

Answer (score 2):

Don't argue with the journal over something as minor as this. Nothing good can come out of it. Just do it and forget about the matter.

Trying to fault someone for this kind of minor error is never a winning strategy in any case, because [finding fault in someone is one of the easiest ways to destroy a relationship](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/liking-the-child-you-love/201502/how-fault-finding-destroys-loving-relationships).

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I think that needs more explanation. Indeed, the journal is already faulting OP, so why should OP be the party to budge? It's also not impossible that something good can come out of it. Maybe the request for the corrigendum came from some overly eager assistant editor, but the editor-in-chief would be fine with an erratum.